# Side-by-side configuration error on Windows

Tags: windows, salt-stack, side-by-side

I have installed Salt (version 2014.1.3) on Windows (Server 2008 R2).
When I tried to launch *salt-minion.exe* I have This error :
`the application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration incorrect`.

I have installed *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable*, but I don't fix the problem.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem is resolved. 
I have downloaded `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)`. The link is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29).